# Possible to construct a function that is nowehere continuous at [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis

Problem: Construct a function *f* that is nowhere continuous at [0,1].

How would this be possible? If 1 and 0 are included, how can it not be continuous at the endpoints of the interval? I think I'm really overthinking this one.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n^3 x)}{n}$$ Best wishes in actually proving it is nowhere continuous on $[0,1]$ :D

Comment: It is pretty challenging to show that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n^3 x)}{n}=\frac{\pi}{6}\neq 0,$$ give it a try.

Comment: Why would it need to be continuous at the end points? Other functions don't need to be continuous at 0 and 1 so why should this be any different?  The real question is can a function be discontinuous at all points of an interval.  And for that, why not?

Comment: How could it not be continuous at the endpoints?  By having  an epsilon so that there will always be an x where  |f (x)-f(1)|> epsilon for so $x-\delta <x <1$ for all possible deltas.  That is not impissible.

Comment: You're right, I was thinking completely wrong. In my class we just had an example that showed a function that is just a point is continuous at that point. This is my first theoretical class ever, so I'm having trouble.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm typically a big fan, but here someone has to say "come on now". I mean given what the OP says about automatic continuity at endpoints, surely that example is simply impossible.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Otoh I find it fascinating. Not clear to me how to show the series even converges for every $x$, although that's certainly plausible. An everywhere-convergent nowhere-continuous trig series, who knew?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: pointwise convergence is a consequence of Weyl's inequality, nowhere-continuity a consequence of explicit estimations carried out through convolutions with approximate identities of the $m^3 e^{-m^3 x}\mathbb{1}_{x\geq 0}$ kind. The previous series is a bad brother (or sister) of a [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=1$ if $x\in[0,1]$ is rational, and $f(x)=0$ if $x\in[0,1]$ is irrational.

Comment: I am having issues visualizing this.

Comment: That's good: if the function has a smooth graph it might well be continuous. My $f$ has a graph with a zillion dotty points on the line $y=1$ and another zillion dotty points on the line $y=0$, and the eye cannot judge how they mesh together.  Points with close $x$ values might have $y$ values that are far from each other.

Comment: How could this be applied to the definition: The statement that the function f is continuous at the point p = (x,y) means that: 1). p is a point on f, and 2). if S is any open interval containing the number f(x), then there is an open interval T containing the number x such that if t is an element of T, and t is in the domain of f, then f(t) is an element of S

Comment: To the proposer:  For the $f$ of this answer:  For $x\in [0,1] $ let $S=(-1/2+f(x),1/2+f(x)). $ Now  if $T$ is $any$ open interval containing $x$ then $T\cap [0,1]$ contains both rationals and irrationals,  so $\{f(t): t\in T\cap [0,1]\}=\{0,1\}$   is NOT a subset of $S.$ So $f$ is not continuous at $x.$